# Forcing evaluation order of `std::pair` constructors; a progress bar `struct` for a for-loop

Tags: c++, progress-bar, c++20, evaluation, std-pair

I'm writing a program containing many long for-loops, and I want to add a progress bar indicator to each. To do this, I wrote `struct ProgressBar` to accomplish this. The interface is as follows:

```cpp
struct ProgressBar {
    int start, end;  // starting and ending values of the loop variable
    const int &curr; // const reference to the loop variable

    /* Update the progress bar by inspecting the current value of "curr" */
    void update();

    /* Constructor; the reference "curr" is initialized in the member initializer list, as it must be */
    ProgressBar(int start, int end, const int &curr);

    ~ProgressBar() {
        cout << "100% done" << endl;
    }
};
```

And the idealized usage is

```cpp
for (auto [i, pb] = pair{0, ProgressBar(0, 100, i)}; i <= 100; ++i) {
    pb.update();
    /* ... */
}
```

This does not work for at least two reasons:

- `ProgressBar(0, 100, i)` causes a compiler error, since it depends on the loop variable `i`, whose type has not been deduced yet (`error: use of ‘i’ before deduction of ‘auto’`).
- `ProgressBar(0, 100, i)` needs to be evaluated after `i`, but I believe the `pair` constructor, like all C++ functions, does not guarantee any particular order of evaluation of parameters of functions.

Any design ideas for what I should do instead?

Comment: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to clog up the drain." - Scotty, Star Trek III. Have you considered simply having `curr` a normal class member and initialized to 0, then implementing the obvious overloads and having a simple loop, that deals with just one object?

Comment: `auto [i, pb] = pair{0, ProgressBar(0, 100, i)};` please spare your coworkers

Comment: Make `ProgressBar` behave like an `int` (overload all relevant operators) so you don't need a separate counter. Just `pb++` should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need two variables to count the loop? Can you not include the state as part of the `progress bar`.

Then you simply need a way of exposing the current state (either as some getter or simply check if it is done via boolean check) and a way of updating it. You could use `update()` as that method (or add ++ to your class).

```
#include <iostream>

class PB
{
    int beg;
    int end;
    int current;
    public:
        PB(int beg, int end)
            : beg(beg)
            , end(end)
            , current(beg)
        {}
        explicit operator bool()  {return current != end;}
        PB& operator++()          {++current;return *this;}
        void update()
        {
            std::cout << current << "\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    for (auto pb = PB(1,100); pb; ++pb) {
        pb.update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a ranged-based for loop.

```
for (type x : expression) {
  // code
}
```

will expand to (if the suitable method exists):

```
{
  auto&& __range = expression;
  auto __it = __range.begin();
  auto __fence = __range.end();
  for (; __it != __fence; ++__it) {
    type x = *__it;
    // code
  }
}
```

If we want a `pb` variable separate from the iterator, we do this:

```
for (auto[x, pb] : ProgressBar(expression)) {
  // code
}

{
  auto&& __range = ProgessBar(expression);
  auto __it = __range.begin();
  auto __fence = __range.end();
  for (; __it != __fence; ++__it) {
    auto[x, pb] = *__it;
    // code
  }
}
```

so we just need `*` to return the appropriate stuff and ++ on the iterator to keep track of the stuff we like.

We can make this work for an arbitrary range-expression by storing it within the `ProgressBar` return value.  We can use `std::distance` to work out how long the range is as well; note that this won't work with io type iterators.  (I would take an optional manual distance argument).

```
template<class Range>
struct Progress {
  Range r;
  std::size_t count = -1;
  Progress(Range&& range, std::size_t c = -1):
    r(std::forward<Range>(range))
    count(c)
  {
    if (count == -1) {
      using std::begin; using std::end;
      count = std::distance( begin(r), end(r) );
    }
  }
  auto begin() const { /* todo */ }
  auto end() const { /* todo */ }
};
```

now we just need to write iterator adaptors for begin/end.  These store a Range iterator, plus count information (current and max).  `++` increases both the Range iterator and the value of current.

`operator*` on these adapters returns a pair of references to both `*` on the Range iterator, plus a progress report object with current/max in it.

If you want your progress report to have something else useful, you'd pass it through the `ProgressBar` function and `Progress` constructor, and store a reference or pointer to it in the iterators.

The big downside is that rolling your own iterator is annoying.  Your advantage is that if you only want to support `for(:)` loops, you don't have to make an actual iterator -- you just have to properly handle `!=`, `++` and `*`.